# how to set firstday in fullcalendar after init

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to set the `firstDay` without having to re-init the whole [calendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/firstDay/).

Is there any way I can achieve that programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [dynamic option](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/) function of fullcalendar?

**EDIT:**
Which version do you use? I found this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38484688/7445344) where the solution was the update..

Comment: How many time do you want to change the `firstDay`? I know it's ugly solution, but what if if you re-init your fullcalendar everytime?

Comment: i'm trying to update fullcalendar right now ! i'll get back to you as soon as i test it (y) !